# ApplicationSettings Class (Store, Restore, Disable, Reset)

Tags: unit-testing, vba, excel

Update: This question has a follow-up [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142793/applicationsettings-class-for-disabling-restoring-application-state)

---

A utility class to handle the ubiquitous "turn off `ScreenUpdating, Calculation, Events` etc" for executing VBA code, and remembering what those values were before they were changed so they can be restored later on.

Also comes with a module of Unit Tests (courtesy of [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/)'s Unit Testing framework).

---

How can I make it even better?

---

### Example Usage

```
Sub Example()

    Dim appSettings As ExcelApplicationSettings
    Set appSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    Set appSettings.TargetApplication = Application

    appSettings.Disable

    '/ Code

    '/ Code

    '/ Code

    '/ Code

    '/ Code

    appSettings.Restore

End Sub
```

### Class `ExcelApplicationSettings`

```
'@Folder Application_Settings

Option Explicit

'/ Object to store, reset and restore application settings for an Excel Application Instance

Private TargetApp As Excel.Application
Private Type AppSettings
    ScreenUpdating As Boolean
    EnableEvents As Boolean
    Calculation As XlCalculation
End Type
Private this As AppSettings

Public Property Set TargetApplication(ByRef target As Excel.Application)

    Set TargetApp = target
    Me.Store

End Property

Public Sub Store()
    '/ Stores the target application's settings

    With TargetApp
        this.ScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        this.EnableEvents = .EnableEvents
        this.Calculation = .Calculation
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub Restore()
    '/ Sets the target's application settings back to their last stored values

    With this
        TargetApp.ScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        TargetApp.EnableEvents = .EnableEvents
        TargetApp.Calculation = .Calculation
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub Disable()
    '/ Sets the target's application settings to "off"

    With TargetApp
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

End Sub

Public Sub Reset()
    '/ Restore application settings to defaults

    With TargetApp
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

---

### Module `ExcelApplicationSettings_Tests`

```
'@Folder Application_Settings

Option Explicit

Option Private Module

'@TestModule
Private Assert As Object

Private OriginalSettings As ExcelApplicationSettings
Private AppSettings As ExcelApplicationSettings

'@ModuleInitialize
Public Sub ModuleInitialize()
    'this method runs once per module.
    Set Assert = CreateObject("Rubberduck.AssertClass")

    Set OriginalSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    Set OriginalSettings.TargetApplication = Application

End Sub

'@ModuleCleanup
Public Sub ModuleCleanup()
    'this method runs once per module.

    OriginalSettings.Restore

End Sub

'@TestInitialize
Public Sub TestInitialize()
    'this method runs before every test in the module.

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    Set AppSettings.TargetApplication = Application

End Sub

'@TestCleanup
Public Sub TestCleanup()
    'this method runs after every test in the module.

    Set AppSettings = Nothing

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestResetPass()
    '/ Reset changes application settings back to default values
    '/ tests for successful reset

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    AppSettings.Reset

    With Application
        Assert.IsTrue .ScreenUpdating, True
        Assert.IsTrue .EnableEvents, True
        Assert.IsTrue .Calculation, xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestResetFail()
    '/ Reset changes application settings back to default values
    '/ tests for expected error when no application object is set

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    AppSettings.Reset '/ should throw an "Error 91, Object variable not set"

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error 91 was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestStoreAndRestorePass()
    '/ Store() stores the target application's settings
    '/ Restore sets the target application's settings to their last-stored values

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    Set AppSettings.TargetApplication = Application

    '/ set all application settings to false
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    '/ store false settings
    AppSettings.Store

    '/change values back to true
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    '/ "restore" the false values
    AppSettings.Restore

    '/ Check for expected false values
    With Application
        Assert.IsTrue .ScreenUpdating, False
        Assert.IsTrue .EnableEvents, False
        Assert.IsTrue .Calculation, xlCalculationManual
    End With

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestStoreFail()
    '/ tests for expected error when no application object is set

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    AppSettings.Store '/ should throw an "Error 91, Object variable not set"

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error 91 was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestRestoreFail()
    '/ tests for expected error when no application object is set

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    AppSettings.Restore '/ should throw an "Error 91, Object variable not set"

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error 91 was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestDisablePass()
    '/ Sets application settings back to their "off" values

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With

    AppSettings.Disable

    With Application
        Assert.IsTrue .ScreenUpdating, False
        Assert.IsTrue .EnableEvents, False
        Assert.IsTrue .Calculation, xlCalculationManual
    End With

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    Assert.Fail "Test raised an error: #" & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Sub

'@TestMethod
Public Sub TestDisableFail()
    '/ tests for expected error when no application object is set

    On Error GoTo TestFail

    Set AppSettings = New ExcelApplicationSettings
    AppSettings.Disable'/ should throw an "Error 91, Object variable not set"

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error 91 was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea, but I find the usage a bit more verbose than it needs to be; IMO the client code for the most basic/common case doesn't need to be any more complicated than this:

```
With New ExcelApplicationSettings
    '...code...
End With
```

I think your write-only `TargetApplication` property is a design issue: if something can be *written to*, it should be possible to also be *read from*.

The only time the client code needs to specify a `TargetApplication` would be when it needs to operate on an instance of `Excel.Application` that is not the current host instance - a rather uncommon scenario: making it necessary for the client code to explicitly specify the instance every time adds an unnecessary burden to the caller. On the other hand, you *want* to be able to specify it if you need to... but then, the caller should be able to validate whether the `TargetApplication` is the global `Application` instance or not.

So either you expose a getter:

```
Public Property Get TargetApplication() As Excel.Application
    Set TargetApplication = TargetApp
End Property
```

*Or* you expose a specialized method *and* a utility function:

```
Public Sub SetTargetApplication(ByVal app As Excel.Application)
    Set TargetApp = app
End Sub

Public Function IsGlobalApplicationInstance() As Boolean
    IsGlobalApplicationInstance = (ObjPtr(TargetApp) = ObjPtr(ThisWorkbook.Application))
End Function
```

Given that the overwhelmingly common use case would be dealing with `ThisWorkbook.Application`, I'd go with the simpler `Get`+`Set` property and leave it up to the client code to determine whether or not `ThisWorkbook.Application` is the encapsulated instance here.

The `TargetApp` private field defeats the purpose of `this` - it should be a member of the `AppSettings` private user-defined type, and I'd drop the "target" and just call it `Application`. Yes, this would "hide" the global `Application` object in the class, but I'll get back to that in a moment.

So we have this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type AppSettings
    Application As Excel.Application
    ScreenUpdating As Boolean
    EnableEvents As Boolean
    Calculation As XlCalculation
End Type
Private this As AppSettings

Public Property Get Application() As Excel.Application
    Set Application = this.Application
End Property

Public Property Set Application(ByVal value As Excel.Application)
    Set .Application = value
    Store
End Property
```

By simply adding this:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Application = ThisWorkbook.Application
End Sub
```

You remove the need for the client code to explicitly set the `Application` reference. Note that the `Excel.Application` parameter doesn't need to be passed `ByRef` to the property; passing an object `ByVal` makes a copy *of the pointer* (not the object!) and passes that - there's nothing particularly costly about it, not more than passing any other `Long` by value.

And then by adding this:

```
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Restore
End Sub
```

You remove the need for the client code to explicitly need to restore the settings before the object goes out of scope - this makes the class play nicely with a `With...End With` block, while still offering the flexibility of being used without.

It also makes `Store` and `Restore` look more "natural" - I don't like how the two aren't using the same `With` block variable, IMO this looks much cleaner:

```
Public Sub Store()
    With Application
        this.ScreenUpdating = .ScreenUpdating
        this.EnableEvents = .EnableEvents
        this.Calculation = .Calculation
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Restore()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = this.ScreenUpdating
        .EnableEvents = this.EnableEvents
        .Calculation = this.Calculation
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub Reset()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm not convinced about publicly exposing the `Store` method: client code that uses this class has a reason to avoid explicitly tampering with `Application.ScreenUpdating` & other settings; exposing `Store` seems like a way to randomize the internal state, which actually makes the class harder to use: the class *encapsulates* a number of flags - this member feels very much like it's breaking that encapsulation: might as well expose each individual flag as a property!

I think I'd also tweak the class' `PredeclaredId` attribute and set it to `True` to make this client code possible:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
With ExcelApplicationSettings.Create(app:=xlApp, autoDisable:=False)
    '...code...
    .Disable
    '...code...
End With
```

...and while tweaking the module attributes, might as well throw in some member attributes and add a `VB_Description` to each public member - because you're using Rubberduck, doing that will give you the member descriptions in the Code Explorer:

[image: RD 2.x Code Explorer]

---

Speaking of Rubberduck, I see you're late-binding the type library. That's great for deploying, but I'd warmly recommend early-binding, at least for typing up your tests.

This raises eyebrows:

> ```
> With Application
>     Assert.IsTrue .ScreenUpdating, True
>     Assert.IsTrue .EnableEvents, True
>     Assert.IsTrue .Calculation, xlCalculationAutomatic
> End With
> ```

I'm sure it wouldn't have looked like this if you had IntelliSense giving you the `Assert.IsTrue` signature:

[image: Sub IsTrue(condition As Boolean, [message As String])]

Did you mean to use `Assert.AreEqual` instead?

[image: Sub AreEqual(expected, actual, [message As String])]

I think this is too many assertions for a single test; if your needs changed and you had to add handling for `Application.DisplayAlerts`, you would have a passing test that should be failing.

Instead, write a test that ensures `ScreenUpdating` gets properly reset. Then *another test* that ensures `EnableEvents` gets properly reset. Then *one more test* that ensures `Calculation` gets properly reset. Then when you want to add handling for `DisplayAlerts`, you won't have any lying test, and nothing to *modify*, only a new test to write.

---

There's one particular use case that's not handled at all, and I think would be useful. Consider code that reports progress using `Application.StatusBar`: it needs `Application.ScreenUpdating` turned off to speed up the processing as much as possible, but then the status bar doesn't get redrawn - and that makes the client code having to manually tweak `Application.ScreenUpdating`, but you could avoid that by exposing a little dedicated method:

```
Public Sub WriteToStatusBar(Optional ByVal value As String = vbNullString)
    this.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    this.Application.StatusBar = value
    this.Application.ScreenUpdating = this.ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: "passing an object ByVal makes a copy of the pointer (not the object!)" I did not know that. That's very useful.

Comment: Can you recommend a naming scheme for Unit-Testing individual paramaters that wouldn't be incredibly verbose.

Comment: Typically that would be something along the lines of `GivenFooThenBar` - verbose test method names are a good thing; you should be able to read the test methods' names in the *Test Explorer* and know exactly what the specs are =)